# Unboxing and casting in one statement in generic method

Tags: c#, generics, casting, boxing

I have a little utility method that looks like so:

```
/// <summary>
/// Replaces a DBNull value with the default of the type specified
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Resulting type</typeparam>
/// <param name="p_this">Object to check for DBNull</param>
/// <returns>p_this if it is not DBNull.Value, else default(T)</returns>
public static T ReplaceDBNullWithDefault<T>(this object p_this)
{
  return p_this == System.DBNull.Value ? default(T) : (T)p_this;
}
```

In my specific scenario, I am taking a record out of a data table and taking a specific field out of it using weak types, and the specific field I'm getting is a `long` which is being boxed into an `object`. An example that reproduces this is as follows:

```
var obj = 2934L;
int num = obj.ReplaceDBNullWithDefault<int>();
```

It fails with an `InvalidCastException`, at `(T)p_this`.

I understand why, the boxed `long` cannot be cast directly to `int`, and trying to do it like this also fails:

```
object myLong = 234L;
int myInt = (int)myLong;
```

However, unboxing and then casting works fine:

```
object myLong = 234L;
int myInt = (int)(long)myLong;
```

How can I work around this in my method?

Comment: Could you elaborate on the reason why you are casting to `int`, and not to `long`? (hence specifying `T` as `long`)

Comment: By providing the correct type ;)

Comment: The field I'm putting the result into is an `int`, not a `long`. I guess I could just do the cast out there.

Comment: `int num = (int)obj.ReplaceDBNullWithDefault<long>();` does not satisfy your needs? However, `int` and `long` is not nullable so this does not cover all scenarios you seem to want to support (and will throw a `NullReferenceException` upon casting). Consider using `int?` and `long?`.

Comment: @StevenJeuris yeah I'm going to go with that. Not worried about nullables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
public static T ReplaceDBNullWithDefault<T>(this object p_this) where T : struct
{
    return 
        p_this == System.DBNull.Value 
            ? default(T) 
            : (T)Convert.ChangeType(p_this, typeof(T));
}
```

Nevertheless you will get an exception if you try to apply this function to a not-convertible type.

So probably it really would be better to cast the value manually to the known type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach:

```
/// <summary>
/// Replaces a DBNull value with the default of the type specified
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Resulting type</typeparam>
/// <param name="value">Object to check for DBNull</param>
/// <param name="tryConvert">if true the object will be converted to the target type if possible, otherwise an InvalidCastException is raised</param>
/// <returns>p_this if it is not DBNull.Value, else default(T)</returns>
/// <exception cref="InvalidCastException">Thrown if the target type is incorrect and the value could not be converted to it</exception>
public static T ReplaceDbNullWithDefault<T>(this object value, bool tryConvert = true)
{
    if (value == System.DBNull.Value || value == null)
        return default(T);
    if (value is T)
        return (T) value;
    if(!tryConvert || !(value is IConvertible))
        throw new InvalidCastException($"Cannot convert {value.GetType()} to {typeof(T)}.");
    return (T)((IConvertible) value).ToType(typeof(T), null);
}
```